# CodeRef macro fails on a wiki page

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In wiki page http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF , a macro to refer to code block doesn't properly shows the result and we see on page:

```
Error: No code_block
```

wiki code looks:

```
{{{#!cplusplus block=broadcaster 
 :
}}}
 :
<<CodeRef(broadcaster, 2, 2)>>
```

which looks correct. Server side issues?

**Env**: Mac OSX 10.6.8, Firefox 3.6.20

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10991/coderef-macro-fails-on-a-wiki-page/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-08-23**:
@tfoote the error can be found after each code citation block for 2 .cpp codes. The error was already there when I first opened the wiki page.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-23**:
It looks correct.  Can you point to where you're trying to use it?

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2013-12-25**:
@tfoote @IsaacSaito
same situation:

http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher
http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29

Env: Ubuntu 12.04, Firefox 25.0.1 / Google Chrome 31.0.1650.63

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2013-12-25**:
BTW How do I start a new line in comment?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-12-26**:
@AzureViolin I took a glimpse at the pages you refer to and found no issues in codes; scope is write. block may be missing from the robot_state_publisher one though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1 day afterward I found the issue is gone. I viewed from the same computer, same environment. What I did is just wait a day and reboot the computer. Good thing is it's solved. Bad is I didn't check other environment. Anyway thanks!

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2011-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0